# Python Equation Maker

Tags: python, formula

What is the best way to alter this loop so that the new_list equation will manipulate the value variable but where I am able to change the equation either by adding directly into the loop as a raw input or by the addition of a variable?

```
#Creating the equation
def f(a_list):
    new_list = []
    for value in a_list:
        new_list += [2 * (value**3) - 1]
    return new_list
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  You would like to change the equation at runtime?

Comment: @RafiGoldfarb so I wanted to be able to change it at run time, so if I wanted to alter the equation 2(value^3) -1 I would be able to at run time

Comment: If you **trust** the user operating with your script, the easiest way would be to ask for the formula as input in valid Python syntax and then evaluate it using `eval`. But if you can't guarantee that the input can be trusted, this is a security problem. The input could be entered in a way that allows the user to run arbitrary shell commands...

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to be able to type an equation to modify every member of the loop the same way:

```
# python3 version
def f(a_list):
    eqn = input("Please enter an equation, using 'x' as the variable: ")
    return [eval(eqn) for x in a_list]
```

(If you are using python 2.x, then use `raw_input` rather than `input`)

Then:

```
>>> f(range(10))
Please enter an equation, using 'x' as the variable: x + 2
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

This is of course an enormous security hole where you assume your user won't enter something like `__import__("os").unlink("some_file_name")` as the equation ...

Comment: Thank you, this worked so much better, although I'm not sure how to modify the equation for when I want to multiply x?